# Redirect to action and pass parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to use
`RedirectToAction("Index", new {id = "some_id"});`
but it makes the url `Index/some_id` instead `Index?id=some_id` that I need.
How to fix it?
**P.S.** I tried to call `RedirectToAction("Index?id=some_id");` but it doesn't work.
**P.P.S.** I decide that it's very easy to make. But I'm noobie in ASP.Net and can't find how.

Comment: That is because of default routing config that is `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Comment: Your using the default routing. If you want a query string instead of a route value, then change the name of the parameter so it does not match the default route (but not clear why you would want that)

Comment: And how do I need to rewrite it?

Comment: I didn't know it. Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

In case you have to route "{controller}/{action}" in your route config, then you can use public ActionResult Index(string id) as your controller method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it already. Just I didn't know about a route config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem, because binder should be able to pick this up and bind the id value for you. If you want you link to be ?param=value do not use id(as parameter) or change your routing config.

Comment: I need to get it like query value